# chmod directories and files in one command?

Tags: permissions, files, directory, chmod

I have a directory "project" that contains a set of subdirectories and files. I want to give 777 permission to the directories and files from my 666 in the same directory with chmod command in my directory "projct". how I can do that ?

Comment: Do you want to change only the files that have 666 or ALL files?

Comment: Please clarify, what do you mean "files from my 666"? Do you want to give 777 to a directory and 666 to the files inside it?

Comment: I edited my question. i wan't to give permissions inside a directory

Answer (score 5):

To do everything in one run:

```
find ./ \( -type d -execdir chmod 755 '{}' \; \) , \( -type f -execdir chmod 644 '{}' \; \)
```

This traverses the tree below the current directory just once and sets 644 on files and 755 on directories.

Answer (score 4):

To recursively give directories read,write&execute privileges to all.

```
sudo find /path/to/the/directory -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

To recursively give files read,write&execute privileges to all.

```
sudo find /path/to/the/directory -type f -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

Comment: chmod also has -R flag for recursive operation.

Comment: Giving 777 permission to files is dangerous.

Comment: `sudo chmod -R 777 /path/to/directroy`

Comment: @AvinashRaj, I think you mean read&write only for files (666). The answer mentions 777 in second command!

Comment: My answer gives read,write,execute permission to all inside a directory recursively.